# Table in R with summary of the data

Tags: r, summary

Is it possible to create a table that looks like this in R? If yes, what package should I use?

Table data summary - source: Geiger, Raghunandan, and Riccardi (2014) - The Global Financial Crisis: U.S. Bankruptcies and Going-Concern Audit Opinions

[image]

Comment: You can look into `kableextra` or `modelsummary`, both are excellent.

Comment: you could also take a look at the `gtsummary` package.